# Requested entity was not found. Type error: storage_user_email

Tags: python, python-3.x, webhook

Hola comunidad estoy empezando en este mundo de la programación y tengo este codigo que recibe una webhook con Python el problema es que en terminar no recibo nada y en gnrok solo observo el siguiente error y que si me llego el mensaje pero en la terminar de mi código no muestra nada anexo imágenes de la terminal y mi código
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
imágenes de la terminal y mi código

```
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    co= request.json
    print("correo completo")
    print (co)
    user_email_id=request.json["user_email_id"]
    print("ID DEL USUERAIO ES : ",user_email_id)
    mj=request.json["user_email"]
    print("email body is : ", mj)
    

if __name__ =='__main__':
   app.run()
```

Comment: Edita la pregunta y publica el código como texto.

Comment: ese `if` está de mas

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS!!! amigo ;)

Comment: @CandidMoe muchas gracias soy nuevo en la plataforma ya lo edite